# Where (and what) can I find in local Google Chrome sql databses?

Tags: python, google-chrome, sqlite

I'm trying to work my way through the book "Violent Python", and I'm on chapter 3...  The exercise walks you through writing some Python scripts to grab Firefox data from the locally stored sql dbs - cool stuff!  But now I want to see if I can do the same for Chrome.  I've seen on some websites that I should be able to find a "urls" db, but I can't seem to figure out where it is.

I've found the Databases.db file, which has tables "databases", "meta", and "sqlite_sequence".  Am I on the right track here?  I want to find things like internet history, bookmarks, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows you'll find the sqlite db for chrome history here:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
```

On Linux:

```
/home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
```

On MacOS-X:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History
```

For more Information look here: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome

I advise you to use: http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to look through the history file.
[image]

Comment: Right, so I got that far (thanks though!).  I guess what I was going for with this question is where is the useful data within these files?  I'm not very familiar with SQL

Comment: Yes, thank you!  Also, the biggest problem I was having (and I just figured it out like 10 minutes ago) was that by having Chrome open, I was locking the database I was trying to read from.  So for anyone else in the same boat as me, close Chrome!!